# Oracle error: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am new to Oracle and would like to know how to make this trigger work please. I can do each trigger separately but I need them all in the same one if that makes sense.

```
    create trigger ID_trigger
    before insert on crime, evidence, offence, officer
    for each row
    begin
    select crime_seq.nextval into :new.crime_id from dual
    and officer_seq.nextval into :new.officer_id from dual
    and evidence_seq.nextval into :new.evidence_id from dual
    and offence_seq.nextval into :new.offence_id from dual;
    end;
```

I initially had a single trigger for each table. However when submitting data into my form the triggers seemed to have overwritten the previous one

Comment: You're trying to create a single trigger that covers four tables, rather than a single trigger on each table? Please start with [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm) to see the correct syntax for the statement. Your select statement is very wrong too.

Comment: I understand that, is it not possible to create a single trigger that covers all four tables? @AlexPoole

Comment: @AlexPoole I initially had a singler trigger for each table, however when sumbitting data into my form the triggers seemed to have overwritten the previous one

Answer (score 1):

> " I initially had a singler trigger for each table, however when
>   sumbitting data into my form the triggers seemed to have overwritten
>   the previous one"

Let's guess: you called all four triggers `id_trigger`.   Each subsequent CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER call would overwrite the first one.   Unless you used CREATE TRIGGER as you do here, in which case each subsequent call would fail,  Either way, only one table would have a trigger.

You see, even though they belong to a table, triggers are separate database objects.  So, like indexes or constraints, their names must be unique within the schema.

The solution is simple: give each trigger a different name, say by including the table name.

Comment: No i named every trigger differently, coinciding with its table name, it still overwrote the previous  @APC

Comment: @Oliver  - Sorry but I think you are mistaken..  Please post a minimal set of code that we can run which exhibits this behaviour.